# Using database objects in functions

Tags: php, function, global-variables

In a webapp I am building I make use of a PDO database object for querying my database.
This is instantiated at the top of every page using a custom class that I built based on PDO:

```
$db = new database; //database is the name of my class.
```

I then use the class like so in my script:

```
$db->query("SELECT field FROM table");
$results = $db->resultset();
```

I have a number of standalone functions that need to make use of the database object.

My question is is it better practise to pass the `$db` to the function as an argument or just globalize from within the function, given `$db` is a globally used variable. However I have heard things about avoiding polluting the global namespace.

i.e.

```
function myFunction($db, $a1, $a2){
    //stuff
}
```

vs

```
function myFunction($a1, $a2){
    global $db;
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, global vars are rarely a good practice. I think you should use the first solution: passing the db instance as first parameters to your function.

IF you only have one instance of your `database`, an even better option would be to make your `database` class a singleton.
This would allow you to do something like `$db = database.getInstance();` in your functions.